# Rust: How to define a closure which can return either Result<T, MyErrorType> or Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define a generic closure such that it can return a `Result` containing any type of error and, in particular, either a specific error or a generic one within a `Box`.  I've got a playground example illustrating what I'm trying to do [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46f6d2af87c73cb191ae0e3be37dfa96), but here is a shortened version:

```
fn try_with_context<T, F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>>(
    context: &str,
    block: F,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>> {
    match block() {
        Ok(v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

I'd like to support the given `block` being able to return either a `Result<T, MyError>` or `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>`, but currently returning `Err(MyError)` fails:

```
fn error_func() -> Result<u8, MyError> {
    Err(MyError {})
}

fn do_something() {    
    // This won't work: Expected Box, found struct MyError
    try_with_context("something", || error_func());
}
```

Now, there are a couple work arounds to make this work:

```
try_with_context("something", || Ok(error_func()));
```

or

```
try_with_context("something", || error_func().map_err(Into::into));
```

Both fix it, but I'm hoping there's a way to define this such that neither of those workarounds are necessary (the `try_with_context` method is part of a library and I find it non-intuitive for a user to have to use these, so I'm hoping to avoid requiring it).

I've played around with introducing another generic to try and address it:

```
fn try_with_context_2<T, U, F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, U>>(
    context: &str,
    block: F,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    U: Error + 'static,
{
    match block() {
        Ok(v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this just reverses the problem here: it's now fine with the `Err(MyError{})` version, but complains about the one returning `Box<dyn Error>`.

A third version does address both of these simple use cases:

```
fn try_with_context_3<T, U, F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, U>>(
    context: &str,
    block: F,
) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    U: Into<Box<dyn Error>>,
{
    match block() {
        Ok(v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
    }
}
```

But as I tried more complex versions of `block`, error come up in weird ways, for example:

```
try_with_context("something", || {
    other_error_func()?;
    error_func()?
});
```

Complains about `'?' couldn't convert the error to 'MyError'`, but:

```
try_with_context("something", || {    
    error_func()?;
    other_error_func()
});
```

is fine.

Is there a good way to define the closure that would handle all of these cases without the workarounds?

EDIT:
I've thought more about this after reading @isaactfa's answer and realized it does come down to something fundamental: I'm effectively trying to define a method that can return *either* a specific type which implements `Error`, or a `Box<dyn Error>`, so I need the generic to be broad enough to allow for either of those two possibilities, *but* this means (at least in every iteration I've tried) that if the explicit return of that function returns a specific type that implement `Error`, then the compiler will try and coerce any earlier `?` style returns into that specific error type, which doesn't work.  I'd still love to hear if there's a clever way to work around this, but in the meantime I will use one of the workarounds I mentioned above (and will probably define some helper function wrapper around `.map_err(Into::into)` to make it a bit more ergonomic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in

```rust
try_with_context_3("something", || {
    other_error_func()?;
    error_func()
});
```

you're returning a `Result<_, MyError>` so Rust expects that to be the return type. The `?` operator is smart enough to try and convert all other error types it encounters into the actually returned error type. This really only leaves you with two options: Force the closure to always return a `Box<dyn Error + 'static>`, and make that ergonomic, maybe by providing an appropriate constructor for your custom error type, or to provide a way for `?` to convert a `Box<dyn Error + 'static>` into a `MyError`:

```rust
impl From<Box<dyn Error + 'static>> for MyError {
    fn from(_t: Box<dyn Error + 'static>) -> Self {
        MyError
    }
}
```

With that in place this'll compile:

```rust
fn do_something() {
    try_with_context_3("something", || error_func());

    try_with_context_3("something", || other_error_func());

    try_with_context_3("something", || {
        other_error_func()?;
        error_func()
    });

    try_with_context_3("something", || {
        error_func()?;
        other_error_func()
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does solve that compiler issue but doesn't allow for any error to be returned; it effectively requires every error to be convertible to whichever one might be returned first, is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant whichever one is returned last (used as the explicit return)

Comment: Your first point (`Force the closure to always return a Box<dyn Error + 'static>, and make that ergonomic`) is what I'd like to do, but I'm wondering if there's some clever way to make it ergonomic (i.e. not apply either of the workarounds I describe in the first post).  One idea I had was to define a custom trait which would implement `FnOnce`, and I would implement that trait for both `FnOnce() -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>` and `FnOnce() -> Result<T, E: Error>` but apparently you can't implement `FnOnce` in stable :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to come up with. It works by requiring that the error can become a box if it isn't one already.

```rust
fn try_with_context<T, R, F>(_context: &str, block: F) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, R>,
    R: Sized + Into<Box<dyn Error>>,
{
    match block() {
        Ok(v) => Ok(v),
        Err(e) => Err(e.into()),
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2037930db9e4fd5c013762c5809b64e3)

The issue you ran into with part 3 is a bit of a non-issue since a it isn't possible to define a function for the erroring use case in the first place so it can never be resolved.

The issue lies with the closure in this case since the Rust compiler is unable to determine a suitable return type for the closure before testing if it works for `try_with_context`.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as the final version considered and rejected in the question?

Comment: Your right, I jumped the gun on posting this. I need to revise it more to better address the question.